# add colorbox to flickr jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, flickr

Does anyone know how to make colorbox work with this flickr jquery plugin?

```
(function($){$.fn.flickr=function(o){var s={api_key:null,type:null,photoset_id:null,text:null,user_id:null,group_id:null,tags:null,tag_mode:'any',sort:'date-posted-asc',thumb_size:'s',size:null,per_page:100,page:1,attr:'',api_url:null,params:'',api_callback:'?',callback:null};if(o)$.extend(s,o);return this.each(function(){var list=$('<ul>').appendTo(this);var url=$.flickr.format(s);$.getJSON(url,function(r){if(r.stat!="ok"){for(i in r){$('<li>').text(i+': '+r[i]).appendTo(list);};}else{if(s.type=='photoset')r.photos=r.photoset;list.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+r.photos.page+'" />');list.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+r.photos.pages+'" />');list.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+r.photos.perpage+'" />');list.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+r.photos.total+'" />');for(var i=0;i<r.photos.photo.length;i++){var photo=r.photos.photo[i];var t='http://farm'+photo['farm']+'.static.flickr.com/'+photo['server']+'/'+photo['id']+'_'+photo['secret']+'_'+s.thumb_size+'.jpg';var h='http://farm'+photo['farm']+'.static.flickr.com/'+photo['server']+'/'+photo['id']+'_';switch(s.size){case'm':h+=photo['secret']+'_m.jpg';break;case'b':h+=photo['secret']+'_b.jpg';break;case'o':if(photo['originalsecret']&&photo['originalformat']){h+=photo['originalsecret']+'_o.'+photo['originalformat'];break;};default:h+=photo['secret']+'.jpg';};list.append('<li><a href="'+h+'" '+s.attr+' title="'+photo['title']+'"><img src="'+t+'" alt="'+photo['title']+'" /></a></li>');};if(s.callback)s.callback(list);};});});};$.flickr={format:function(s){if(s.url)return s.url;var url='http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&jsoncallback='+s.api_callback+'&api_key='+s.api_key;switch(s.type){case'photoset':url+='&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id='+s.photoset_id;break;case'search':url+='&method=flickr.photos.search&sort='+s.sort;if(s.user_id)url+='&user_id='+s.user_id;if(s.group_id)url+='&group_id='+s.group_id;if(s.tags)url+='&tags='+s.tags;if(s.tag_mode)url+='&tag_mode='+s.tag_mode;if(s.text)url+='&text='+s.text;break;default:url+='&method=flickr.photos.getRecent';};if(s.size=='o')url+='&extras=original_format';url+='&per_page='+s.per_page+'&page='+s.page+s.params;return url;}};})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the Flickr plugin, but here is a short guide to [using colorbox with flickr](http://jacklmoore.com/notes/colorbox-with-json-or-flickr).  Interfacing with Flickr is pretty easy since it returns a JSON object.